# Can't SSH after creating an Instance from Command line

Tags: ssh, permissions, openstack, devstack

I am creating an instance from command line using command

```
nova boot --no-service-net --no-public --disk-config AUTO --config-drive=true --flavor 2 --key-name key1 --image c28bc1e8-a25f-413c-9e13-fecdd5d6f522 test
```

when instance launched successfully I tried to ssh instance by using this command

```
ssh -i key1.key fedora@10.0.0.10
```

but it gives me an permission error,

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

And when I create an instance from Dashboard/Horizon. I can ssh without any problem or issue with the same command `ssh -i key2.key fedora@10.0.0.12`

Guide me what is the problem why I can't ssh after creating an instance from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in ssh key generation, I was generating ssh key like

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f newdemokey.key
```

and then add this key into nova keypair-list. That was not working to ssh instance

But the best way is to generate ssh key is,

```
ssh-keygen
```

And add this key into nova keypair-list,

```
nova keypair-add --pub-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test-key
```

It will work  with the new instance to ssh.